# How can i make several instances of button/label/image in a view controller?

Tags: ios

for a new project for iOS, i would like to add several instances of an object on a single view controller.
Each object would be made of a Button, a Label and probably a ImageView. I want to stay on iOS5 (iPad 1 compatibility) and don't want to use UIViewCollection.

The number of these objects will be fixed : 3 lines and 3 columns but the parameters inside will be different for each object.

For the moment, i have made a View in my View Controller to handle the first instance (see the screenshot)

But how can i do to make 8 other subviews like that without duplicating everything ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you can make the objects programmatically for instance...

Comment: and i could use Array of Views or Labels ?   and what about the methods for button taps ?

Comment: yes, you can use `NSArray` to store them, but you could use the `IBOutletCollection` for it, which is the good solution if you created the objects in the _Interface Builder_. however the objects are in the current view's `subviews` property (`NSArray`) as well. you can find them among the all other views.

Comment: Or you can try creating a custom UIView class that has the subviews you'd like to add built in. Each button will be handled inside its own custom UIView object.